# No granted memory when running query from entity

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

Using EntityFrameworkCore, I noticed one of my queries reached a timeout (>30s), so I used debug and copy/pasted the `DebugView.Query` expression from my `IQueryable` object to SSMS, and it ran just fine in less than 1s.

I then opened the Activity Monitor in SSMS and re-ran the query from entity to check its execution plan and compare it with the one I got when I ran the query inside SSMS.

I noticed two main differences :

- In the `StatementText` part, the plan with Entity includes the parameters (which looks like `(@__start_Value_0 datetime,@__p_1 int,@__p_2 int)`) and only this differs from the plan I got with the same query in SSRS.
- The `MemoryGrantInfo` part differs a lot.

This is what I get when I run the query directly in SSMS:

```xml
<MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="5632" SerialDesiredMemory="22112" RequiredMemory="13568" DesiredMemory="30048" RequestedMemory="30048" GrantWaitTime="0" GrantedMemory="30048" MaxUsedMemory="12248" MaxQueryMemory="585360" />
```

This is what I get when I run the query with Entity:

```xml
<MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="3584" SerialDesiredMemory="7216" GrantedMemory="0" MaxUsedMemory="0" />
```

I understand that speed can directly be related to granted memory, but what I don't understand is **why wouldn't SQL Server grant any memory to Entity's queries?**

---

If it is of any use, the query itself is as simple as:

```sql
DECLARE @__start_Value_0 datetime = '2020-01-01T00:00:00.000';
DECLARE @__p_1 int = 0;
DECLARE @__p_2 int = 100;

SELECT [l].[A],[l].[B],[l].[C],[l].[D]
FROM [MyView] AS [l]
WHERE [l].[D] > @__start_Value_0
ORDER BY [l].[D] DESC, [l].[A], [l].[B]
OFFSET @__p_1 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_2 ROWS ONLY
```

and if I remove any of the 3 order bys (no matter which one), query works fine with Entity.

---

[Execution plan (with Entity)](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJUJioiDc)

[Execution plan (from SSMS)](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryV0TniPq)

```sql
SELECT @@VERSION
```

> Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB4583458) - 15.0.2080.9 (X64)   Nov  6 2020 16:50:01   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

---

### Edit:

I ended up adding an interceptor as suggested by @SvyatoslavDanyliv, but with `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` and query time effectively dropped significantly. I've configured my interceptor for both options in case this one no longer works for my use cases.
However, I am still wondering why there was no `GrantedMemory` although required and desired memory were non-zero.

Comment: [Erland's article](https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) explains why the SSMS and app plan may differ. Upload the actual execution plans to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the links to your question for to facilitate an answer.

Comment: What's the output of `SELECT @@VERSION` on your instance of SQL Server?

Comment: Looks like Parameter Sniffing, which is a problem with EF Core.

Comment: @DanGuzman added the execution plan I got with Entity

Comment: @AlwaysLearning added output for `SELECT @@VERSION`

Comment: @Rafalon, can you add the SSMS plan too? Not suggesting it's related but your SQL is years behind in patching.

Comment: If your instance is also doing a lot of columnstore bulk inserts then there are memory grant time out fixes in SQL Server 2019 CU12 that may help. We're up to CU16 now, btw.

Comment: @DanGuzman added SSMS plan (I dont have the rights access to do the patching myself)

Comment: I would suggest to try interceptor like in this [article](https://lizzy-gallagher.github.io/query-interception-entity-framework/) but you have to add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`. If it works, add such option to SQL which has specific comment added by `TagWith`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv thanks, I'll try that tomorrow and tell here if it worked